# Expected ref to be a function or a string error using the @fullcalendar package in React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying the tutorial from

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

and whenever I go to run the program, I get that error "Expected ref to be a function or a string." and then 38 frames stacked. I don't quite understand why I am getting this error.

```
import React from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actionCreators } from '../store/Counter';
import './Calendar.css'

class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
             <div>
                <FullCalendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" plugins= 
                {[dayGridPlugin]} />
            </div>
        );
    }
 }

 export default connect(
    state => state.events,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
 )(MyApp);
```